# Guess the return type of a selecting function

Tags: typescript

```
const stateObj = {
  property: {
    nested: "someString"
  }
}

const makeSelector = (selectingFunction) => state => selectingFunction(state); // may include some addiitonal logic, such as memoization

const selector = makeSelector((state: typeof stateObj) => state.property.nested);

const out = selector(stateObj); // How do I make TypeScript guess its type?
```

I'd like TypeScript to be able to guess the type of `out` (which is a string) - how do I do this?

Comment: Side note: The term is "infer" (rather than "guess"). Just for searching purposes. :-) The feature is "type inference."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign generic type parameters to `makeSelector` that will make it possible for TypeScript to infer the return type of the returned function:

```typescript
const stateObj = {
    property: {
        nested: "someString"
    }
};

const makeSelector = <StateType, ReturnType>(selectingFunction: (state: StateType) => ReturnType) => (state: StateType) => selectingFunction(state);
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^−−−−−^−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^

const selector = makeSelector((state: typeof stateObj) => state.property.nested);

const out = selector(stateObj);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=12&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBNCGUCmB5ARgKxgXhgbwFgAoGUmABwCcRylKoBPALn2LPZjCWiQBMWARBBABbJAGUolAJZgA5gLZkAvsWUBuYsVCRYI+AGsJSADZJgUEJRwwAPJMRIAKg1oAaGACUkUAK6UwF1oAPgAKCFNzKFk5ADFfMAtpcBZwqEcWB2QgpABKHGCvH39A1zyCmDSMmCznMvzsQoizJPl4xOjwKuRczSJtcGg4SIsrG30jcRHLSlDupBZGWhAAMzh05HQMBqaNpAA6Kho6Rn2uHl5erSIdIZBfWFxmqKt5rauiIA)